# Derivation of microscopic Ohm's law from macroscopic version?

Tags: electromagnetism, semiconductors, electromagnetic, ohms-law, solid-state-devices

What I tried was:

$$\overrightarrow{E}= - \triangledown V      \qquad \qquad\qquad\qquad  (1) $$
$$V= IR\qquad \qquad\qquad\qquad\text{(Ohm's law for materials where V}\propto \text{I)}$$
$$\text{Assuming a box of length x and cross-sectional area A}$$
$$=> \frac{dV}{dx}=R\frac{dI}{dx}+I\frac{dR}{dx}\qquad \qquad\qquad\qquad\text{(assuming 1 dimensional current flow)}$$
$$ =>\frac{dV}{dx}=I\frac{dR}{dx}\qquad \qquad\qquad\qquad\text{(assuming uniform current)}\qquad \qquad(2)$$
$$ \text{from equation 1}$$
$$ -E_x=\frac{dV}{dx}\qquad \qquad\qquad\qquad\text{(assuming 1 dimension)}\qquad \qquad\qquad\qquad(3)$$
$$ \text{from equation 2 and 3}$$
$$=> -E_x=I\frac{dR}{dx}$$
$$=> -E_x=\overrightarrow{J}.\overrightarrow{A}\frac{dR}{dx}$$
$$=> -E_x=J_xA_x\frac{dR}{dx}$$
$$=> -(\sigma)E_x=J_x$$
$$=> \overrightarrow{J}=-\sigma\overrightarrow{E}$$

I just proved that the current density vector is antiparallel to the electric field vector. I know this is wrong but I couldn't find the mistake.
I know some people may argue that I have probably missed a negative sign owing to the electrons, but what about the holes?

Moreover, this is a general equation for charge q. The sign should take care of itself, irrespective of the type of charge.

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe A is oriented antiparallel (in opposite direction) to J, not in the same.

Comment: Agree here: \$V = -\int_{x_{_0}}^x \mathscr{E}_x\:\text{d}x\$, then \$\frac{\text{d}\,V}{\text{d}x}=-\mathscr{E}_x\$ and is constant. But I don't like the way you sneak in \$\text{d}l\$ as a replacement for \$\text{d}x\$. Either remain consistent here or tell me how the meaning is different. Is there any difference between these? And after you answer, I've another question.

Comment: @jonk ! You were right. I shouldn't have used dl and dx interchangeably and yes they are the same. I have made the necessary edits in the question itself.  Thanks

Comment: @Curd ! No. $$ \overrightarrow{J}=\sigma\overrightarrow{E}$$ is a more general case and holds true . The most general equation is $$ \overrightarrow{J}=\sigma\overrightarrow{f}$$ where f is force per unit charge. Assuming only electromagnetic forces at work, it becomes $$ \overrightarrow{J}=\sigma\overrightarrow{E}+\overrightarrow{v}\times\overrightarrow{B}$$. And again assuming velocity of charges negligible(which is not in the case of plasmas but it is in most conductors), it becomes $$ \overrightarrow{J}=\sigma\overrightarrow{E}$$

Comment: @CuriousCosmopolitan Well, the photon pretty much picked out the issue. Either dR/dx is negative, which you missed, or else dV/dx is negative. Either way, you missed the sign here.

Comment: @Curious Cosmopolitan: I don't see how this answers the question whether  \$\vec{A}\$ in your formula is oriented the right way that you can simply replace \$\vec{J}\vec{A}\$ by \$JA\$ (and not by \$-JA\$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you missed the sign in your Eq. (2). It should be:

$$ \frac{dV}{dx}=-I\frac{dR}{dx}\qquad \qquad\qquad\qquad\text{(assuming uniform current)}\qquad \qquad(2)$$

because the voltage drops (rather than increases) as you pass along a volume element of the resistor.

The fundamental problem is that the macroscopic form of Ohm's law ignores all concepts of direction, so really you should derive the macroscopic form from the microscopic form rather than vice versa.

Comment: Yes, that was going to be my second question in comments. I was saving it, though, and I certainly would not have made an answer of it. There are two ways of looking at this same issue. Either way, the sign wasn't set up right. I'll +1 anyway. It's sufficient.

Comment: @The Photon ! Thanks a ton. Got your point.